# how to read umlaut from file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, file

i am creating a program to read some files.
while reading 1 of the files i encountered some umlaut characters in the file.
how should i read those characters 
& store them in string?
currently i am using `string::getline()` which is unable to read these characters & the position of reading pointer is not incrementing.
the character is in a line preceded by some spaces.
so i am using `ws` to remove the spaces.
i used `peek` to understand the problem; while hovering over the peek o/p char VS2010 showed y with 2 dots on it. so i guess it is umlaut character.

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Step 1: Read about Unicode. Step 2: Use `wstring`.

Comment: ok thanks!
very informative :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is what you need - This code reads from file (UTF-8) text in German, prints it on console and saves in output file -

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
//To handle localized input -
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{

//read from file - 
    std::ifstream stream("c:\\temporary\\in.txt");
    std::string line;

    if (stream.is_open()) 
    { 
        std::getline(stream, line);
    }

//print on console -
    if(!SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8)) { // 65001
        std::cerr << "Failed to set console output mode!\n";
        return 1;
    }
    HANDLE const consout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD nNumberOfCharsWritten;
    const char* utf8 = line.c_str();
    if(!WriteConsoleA(consout, utf8, strlen(utf8), &nNumberOfCharsWritten, NULL)) {
        DWORD const err = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "WriteConsole failed with << " << err << "!\n";
        return 1;
    }

//write to file -
    std::fstream myfile;
    myfile.open("c:\\Temporary\\out.txt",std::ios::out);
    if (myfile.is_open()) 
    { 

        myfile << line <<"\n"<<std::endl;
    } 
    myfile.flush();
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much!
in which data type should i store the unicode character apart from w_char?

Comment: Just returned from a long trip. Anyway, you can use char (UTF-8), wchar_t (UTF-16), and in C++11 there are char16_t (UTF-16) plus char_32t (utf-32). See this book for details-http://books.google.co.il/books?id=sN_0ovp_yv4C&pg=PT515&lpg=PT515&dq=wide+character+in+C%2B%2B&source=bl&ots=LjDWr1DDHE&sig=zwbiVlWzajJFDD29G37IlPh_59s&hl=en&sa=X&ei=K2T5TrbSCsye-Qb_ws2rDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=wide%20character%20in%20C%2B%2B&f=false